# Get users that inserted a row everyday

Tags: mysql

I need to check which users added **an item** every day(**'to_date'** shows the day) since 20 days.

---

```
**Table Structer**
# id         (int pk)
# user_id    (int fk)
# item_id    (int fk)   
# to_date    (datetime)
```

Comment: is there a constraint that prevents users from entering an item _more than once_ per day?

Comment: count the items, group by user_id and filter by date to be between today and 20 days ago.

Comment: @ericosg that doesn't work if the user can put in more than one per day, per my comment

Comment: @Alnitak, true, we need that clarification. otherwise add the current day to the group by. then the count must be 20 to satisfy.

Comment: user can add items more than one per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT    user_id, COUNT(DISTINCT to_date) AS n
FROM      mytable
WHERE     to_date > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 20 DAY) 
GROUP BY  user_id
HAVING    n = 20
```

You may need to tweak the `DATE_SUB` clause to match your exact requirements.

Comment: this is the missing part `GROUP BY user_id`

Comment: @UğurÖzpınar sorry, yes, I had that when I tested it but missed it in copy&paste